# How to get the name of the current git branch into a variable in a shell script?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am new to shell scripting and can't figure this out. If you are unfamiliar, the command git branch returns something like

```
* develop
  master
```

, where the asterisk marks the currently checked out branch. When I run the following in the terminal:

```
git branch | grep "*"
```

I get:

```
* develop
```

as expected.

However, when I run

```
test=$(git branch | grep "*")
```

or

```
test=`git branch | grep "*"`
```

And then

```
echo $test
```

, the result is just a list of files in the directory. How do we make the value of test="* develop"?

Then the next step (once we get "* develop" into a variable called test), is to get the substring. Would that just be the following?

```
currentBranch=${test:2}
```

I was playing around with that substring function and I got "bad substitution" errors a lot and don't know why.

Comment: Try [this blog post](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/02/02/bedazzle-your-bash-prompt-with-git-info/).

Comment: What if you use single quotes around the asterisk: `'*'` instead of `"*"`

Comment: @glenn that's not where the expansion happens, it's in the echo, as marco already elaborated upon.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The * is expanded, what you can do is use sed instead of grep and get the name of the branch immediately:

```
branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

And a version using git symbolic-ref, as suggested by Noufal Ibrahim

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
```

To elaborate on the expansion, (as marco already did,) the expansion happens in the echo, when you do `echo $test` with `$test` containing `* master` then the `*` is expanded according to the normal expansion rules. To suppress this one would have to quote the variable, as shown by marco: `echo "$test"`. Alternatively, if you get rid of the asterisk before you echo it, all will be fine, e.g. `echo ${test:2}` will just echo `master`. Alternatively you could assign it anew as you already proposed:

```
branch=${test:2}
echo $branch
```

This will echo `master`, like you wanted.

Comment: It would be courteous of you to mention my answer if you used elements from it to update yours.

Comment: Of course, my apologies, I updated quickly before leaving, missed the attribution.

Comment: ok, so I tried both the methods, and I must say that `symbolic-ref` won't always work. eg: if you checkout some old commit, it throws error, whereas the `sed` command gives something like `(HEAD detached at 1qw23er)`

Comment: Note: the first technique works even if there are forward slashes in the branch name (e.g., because it is an issue URL), why the second one only takes the last segment in that case.

Comment: `sed` makes this even easier, actually!

`branch=$(git branch | sed '/^  /d;s/^\* //')`

Answer (score 141):

Expanding on [Noufal Ibrahim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111192/3303195), use the `--short` flag with `git-symbolic-ref`, no need to fuss with `sed`.

I've been using something like this in hooks and it works well:

```
#!/bin/bash

branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)

echo
echo "**** Running post-commit hook from branch $branch"
echo
```

That outputs "**** Running post-commit hook from branch master"

Note that `git-symbolic-ref` only works if you're in a repository. Luckily `.git/HEAD`, as a leftover from Git's early days, contains the same symbolic ref. If you want to get the active branch of several git repositories, without traversing directories, you could use a bash one-liner like this:

```
for repo in */.git; do branch=$(cat $repo/HEAD); echo ${repo%/.git} :  ${branch##*/}; done
```

Which outputs something like:

```
repo1 : master  
repo2 : dev  
repo3 : issue12
```

If you want to go further, the full ref contained in `.git/HEAD` is also a relative path to a file containing the SHA-1 hash of the branch's last commit.

Comment: `alias currentgitbranch='git symbolic-ref --short HEAD'`

Comment: This is the best answer, using `--short` gets you just the string you are looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

I would use the `git-symbolic-ref` command in the git core. If you say `git-symbolic-ref HEAD`, you will get the name of the current branch.

Comment: In later version of git, you will have to use git symbolic-ref HEAD instead.

Comment: You'd want to use the --short flag to only get the branch name. For an example: While on the master branch  `git-symbolic-ref HEAD` outputs `refs/heads/master` but ` git-symbolic-ref --short HEAD` only outputs `master`

Answer (score 24):

I use this
`git describe --contains --all HEAD`
in my git helper scripts

example:

```
#!/bin/bash
branchname=$(git describe --contains --all HEAD)
git pull --rebase origin $branchname
```

I have that in a file called `gpull` in `~/scripts`

### Edit:

for a lot of CI environments, they'll check your code out in a "detached head" state, so then I'll use:

```
BRANCH=$(\
  git for-each-ref \
  --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/heads \
  | awk "/^$(git rev-parse HEAD)/ {print \$2}"\
)
```

Comment: `git describe --contains --all HEAD` does not give me the current branch as highlighted by a star with `git branch`.

Comment: this was useful in a jenkins build script, thanks

Comment: Attention: With git describe, if you have a tag on HEAD it will give you the tag name instead of branch name.

Answer (score 8):

The problem relies on:

```
echo $test
```

In fact the variable test contains a wildcard which is expanded by the shell. To avoid that just protect $test with double quotes:

```
echo "$test"
```

Answer (score 1):

disable subshell glob expansion,

```
test=$(set -f; git branch)
```

Comment: that's not where the expansion happens, it's in the echo, as marco already elaborated upon.