# Get current branch name or tag name

Tags: git, puppet

I'm writing a Puppet module which manages the branch or tag that is currently checked out on a local Git repository. I'd basically like to enable users to specify which version of a repository they'd like checked out. This could be `master` (a branch) or `v3.6.2` (a tag).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
exec { 'gitolite_select_version':
    command => "git checkout ${actual_version}",
    cwd     => '/usr/src/gitolite',
    path    => '/bin:/usr/bin',
    unless  => "test \"$(git describe --contains --all HEAD)\" == ${actual_version}""
}
```

This works fine on branches like `master`, but gives bad output when on a detached HEAD like a tag. Example on master

```
$ git describe --contains --all HEAD
master
```

Example on tag:

```
$ git describe --contains --all HEAD
tags/v3.6.2^0
```

Is there a Git command which will get me the branch name or current tag in a simple, unified format?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-current-branch-name-in-git, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111042/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-git-branch-into-a-variable-in-a-shell-script.

Comment: Does the `revision` parameter from `vcsrepo` not suffice for your needs?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [puppetlabs-vcsrepo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo)? This is the kind of thing that module manages:

```
vcsrepo { "/usr/src/gitolite":
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
  revision => $actual_version,
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that this was an option, thanks for pointing it out.