# What does 'git merge' with no arguments do?

Tags: git

I've seen people doing

```
git merge
```

i.e. using "git merge" with no arguments. It looks like it might do something useful. But I couldn't find documentation for this scenario on git-scm.com.

What does "git merge" do in this scenario?

Comment: it's a deal......

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would try and merge its upstream branch ([`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))

> If no commit is given from the command line, merge the remote-tracking branches that the current branch is configured to use as its upstream.

So check, to see if a branch has an upstream repo associated to it:

```
git config remote.$(git config branch.$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD).remote).url
```

This uses:

- "[Find out which remote branch a local branch is tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425090/6309)"
- "[How to get the name of the current git branch into a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915331/6309)"

---

For Windows, [crashneb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5844631/crashneb) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504946/what-does-git-merge-with-no-arguments-do/39505019?noredirect=1#comment123652055_39505019):

```
for /f %b in ('git symbolic-ref --short HEAD') do \
  @(for /f %r in ('git config branch.%b.remote') do \
    @(git config remote.%r.url))
```

Comment: Ahhhh riiiiight. It *is* documented, just in a completely unintuitive place. I was scouring the 'Description' section on the grounds that 'no arguments' is a fundamentally different invocation than 'one or more commits specified'. But it's actually documented under the '<commit>' argument. Docs could be improved IMO

Comment: Just in case someone wants a "windows cmd" version that chains it all together like the above:  `for /f %b in ('git symbolic-ref --short HEAD') do @(for /f %r in ('git config branch.%b.remote') do @(git config remote.%r.url))`
(although even on windows the bash syntax above works fine as an alias in the _.gitconfig_ file)

Comment: @CrashNeb Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.